# Maven 3 - Use local repo for locally produced artifacts

Tags: java, maven

Let's say I have an EAR that uses a 3rd party JAR from an online Maven repo, and a local JAR I produce myself, that needs to be pulled from my local repo.

If I build the EAR, it complains that it can't find the local JAR in the repo, because it's looking online. However, that is the correct behaviour for the 3rd party JAR.

How do I get Maven to look locally for artifacts, AND online? I guess it would be best to look locally as a last resort. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The local repository is the first place where Maven looks for artifacts if it does not find them in the local it tries remote repos.

Comment: Where is that defined though? It isn't doing it at the moment because I've made alterations to the settings.xml, but I don't know how to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the .jar file to the local repository.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

or else include the .jar as system dependency.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies